# turning overflow-y off with a setTimeout() function

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i'm developing a project where the scrollbar needs to be hidden and unable to function for the first 4 seconds on the first render, when the site open (there's a gsap animation). so i set the * {overflow-y: hidden} on css and would like to make it auto again after those seconds with a setTimeout() function, how could i proceed?

Comment: Are you using reactjs?

Comment: yes im using react

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector("html").style.overflowY = "hidden";
```

after 4 secs:

```
document.querySelector("html").style.overflowY = "auto";
```

If you don't want to do it this way you could also do this ([Codepen](https://codepen.io/cowall/pen/MWVPbdx)):

```
.class1 {
   overflow-y: hidden;
}

.class2 {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

after 4 seconds just replace class1 with class2 on the node

Third option I give you would be declaring a CSS variable and changing it with js:

```
:root {
  --scrollbar-var: hidden;
}

html {
 overflow-y: var(--scrollbar-var);
}


let root = document.documentElement;
root.style.setProperty('--scrollbar-var', "auto");
```

Comment: hmmm i see, but there's no such class (".scrollbar-container"), it's on * { }, a global effect

Comment: Please see the variable variant I added, or just do document.querySelector('html')

Comment: see this [codepen](https://codepen.io/cowall/pen/MWVPbdx)

Comment: Did you have success or do you need further clarification @Piet

Comment: didn't try yet, ill let you know!